# Getting the right result of mouse click event

Tags: java, events, mouse, awt

I'm curious why I got the "right" BUT "wrong"number of result when I click the mouse.
I supposed to print on the console `mouseClicked` **once** everytimes the mouse is clicked. However I got many of them printed out everytimes I clicked the mouse ...sometimes 5 e.g.

```
mouseClicked
mouseClicked
mouseClicked
mouseClicked
mouseClicked
```

Instead of just

```
mouseClicked
```

Why?

```
public class GUI extends JFrame implements MouseListener, ActionListener {
.....
   public GUI {
      GridBagLayout m = new GridBagLayout();
      Container c = getContentPane();
      c.setLayout (m);
      GridBagConstraints con = new GridBagConstraints();
      ....
      JPanel pDraw = new JPanel(new GridLayout(ROWS,COLS,2,2)); 
      con = new GridBagConstraints();
      ...
      m.setConstraints(pDraw, con);

      pDraw.addMouseListener(this);     
      pack();         
      setVisible(true);       
   }

   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
      System.out.println("mouseClicked");       
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context? Specifically, where does your MouseEventHandler get added as a listener? It looks like you're adding it as a listener more than once.

Comment: It is hard to tell without knowing to what you attach your listener. Please provide more details about the context.

Comment: @Jessy: Could you also provide the code where `addMouseListener` is called?

Comment: @Jessy: Could you modify `mouseClicked` to also print out the `MouseEvent` (`System.out.println(arg0);`) and paste the results?

Comment: @ Adam -- it gave me this result many times

Comment: @Jessy: Are you 100% sure that those results were identical? As per Bozhidar's answer, I am curious about the `clickCount`.

Comment: java.awt.event.MouseEvent[MOUSE_CLICKED,(90,69),absolute(503,141) ....

Comment: I have tried if(e.getClickCount()==1){  .. yet I still get many results

Comment: @Jessy: Hmmm, could you also try printing out the identity hash code of the `MouseEvent` (`System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(arg0));`)? This will determine if the *same* mouse event is repeatedly being passed (not different mouse events that *look* identical).

Comment: @Adam: it gives me this result many times --> 16554308

Comment: @ how could it be.. I @Override the other mouseEvent.

Comment: @Jessy: This is really confusing...

Comment: @Jessy: If you comment out the `pDraw.addMouseListener(this);` part, do you still receive mouse events?

Comment: Without a SSCCE people are just wasting their time. You will only get one mouseClick if you click once on a component. In fact the normal complaint is that you "don't" get a mouse click when you click on a component. This can happen if the mouse moves even 1 pixel between the mousePressed and mouseClicked events.

Comment: Adam@ yes..still get the same result

Comment: @Jessy: Therefore, it looks like *something else* is calling `addMouseListener`.

Comment: yes, I think it because of the mousepressed ... however I have overrides the mousePressed, why this method still implemented.

Comment: @Jessy: I'm a bit confused at your last statement. The point I was making is that something must be calling `addMouseListener` (with your `GUI` object as the argument) ***five times***. If your `GUI` object is registered five times, your `mouseClicked` method will be called five times for each mouse click. Perhaps there is something in the rest of your constructor which is inadvertently calling `addMouseListener` again...

Comment: @Adam : Thanks
@Camickr - Thanks, for pointing out the mousePressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all comments, since I did not implement all methods of mouseEvent, I should use new mouseAdapter() so that it doesn't mixed between mousepressed and mouseClicked.

```
public class GUI extends JFrame implements MouseListener, ActionListener {
.....
   public GUI {
      GridBagLayout m = new GridBagLayout();
      Container c = getContentPane();
      c.setLayout (m);
      GridBagConstraints con = new GridBagConstraints();
      ....
      JPanel pDraw = new JPanel(new GridLayout(ROWS,COLS,2,2)); 
      con = new GridBagConstraints();
      ...
      m.setConstraints(pDraw, con);

      pDraw.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
         public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { 
            System.out.println("mouseClicked");
         } 
      });

      pack();         
      setVisible(true);       
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this method in MouseEvent:

getClickCount

public int getClickCount()
Returns the number of mouse clicks associated with this event.
Returns:
integer value for the number of clicks

Comment: I tried the if(e.getClickCount()==1) but I still get many results

Answer (score 1):

The example you provided looks correct and *should* work.

Since you're implementing the MouseListener interface, you might want to check if you're not accidentally printing "mouseClicked" in the mousePressed/mouseReleased methods.